# how do i make the image take the full width of the screen? (html, css)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

as the title says, im just wondering how to remove the remaining white borders on the right, left and in between the navbar on the top in order for the image to take up the entire width.

[image]

heres what i tried to code (theres bootstrap):

CSS:

```
.img_banner {
  min-height : 100%;
  min-width : 100%;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="container-full col-md-12">
      <img src="img/banner1.jpg" class="center-block img_banner img-responsive portfolio-box">
  </div>
```

Comment: try width: 100vw; height:100vh

Comment: the image still does not take up the entire screen

Comment: you need to post also css of container-full for us to help, also you can inspect the elements in your browser, by inspecting you will be able to whats causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that white space is usually caused by margin in the body. try adding

```
margin: 0;
```

to the body element

---

### EDIT

I just realized you said you're using bootstrap, my best guess is that there's 15px padding on the right and left of column elements. So try adding set these properties in the row element:

```
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;
width: calc(100% + 30px);
```

Comment: thank you for the tip, however the right side is the only one remaining with a white border

Comment: edited my answer again to fixed the white space on the right