# How do I make a gif responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive, gif

I want to make a gif image responsive to resize it to cover the width of every mobile device. This is because for some reason I can get a video to autoplay in certain IOS devices, so I though of converting the video into a gif. Now, how can I make it responsive? I don't really care about the height, is more of a width problem.

this is my oode so far:

```css
.box {
  width: 500px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="examplegif" alt="Example gif" style="width:340px;height:170px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do i make the image take the full width of the screen? (html, css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474679/how-do-i-make-the-image-take-the-full-width-of-the-screen-html-css)

Comment: **DON'T use `!important` if you have any way avoiding it!**

Comment: use width:100%;height:auto; for your image and change the width of the .box class to 100% 

and please refer Tanner Dolby or StepUp's answer
its much more efficient and clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be to remove `width: 500px` from the parent container `.box`. This explicit width restricts the image from being able to fill the entire viewport since it's parent containers width is only 500px. Next, there is an 8px default `margin` on the `<body>` from the user agent stylesheet. Using `margin: 0` within the body styling will ensure there isn't any extra space around your content.

To make the GIF responsive and fill the entire viewport width, you can add some styling to the nested `<img>` elements in `.box`. I gave the images a `width` and [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) of 100% to ensure they take up all the available space. For the image height, use `height: 100%` to make sure it's 100% of the containing blocks height or `height: auto` to let the browser calculate and select a height for the specified element. Try this out.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box{
 width: auto;
}

.box img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* vary this to your needs ie auto, 100%, etc */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/ZqlvCTNHpqrio/giphy.gif" alt="Example gif">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your image responsive by applying the following class to your image.

CSS:

```
.responsive {
    max-width: 100%; 
    width: auto; 
    height: auto;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<img src="ypurgif" class="responsiveImage" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the maximum width to the image or video in this case of the gif.

```html
<style>
    .box {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/VRhsYYBw8AE36/giphy.gif" alt="Example gif">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```